# LEFT JOIN-ing the same MySQL View multiple times makes some of the Views derived

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a Hibernate-generated query that LEFT OUTER JOINs MySQL Views on some of the columns.

The query performs really poor so I EXPLAIN-ed it and found that in some cases the same View is treated as a derived select.

Here is my query generated by Hibernate. I have simplified it for the sake of the example:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   `task` `task` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `view_users` `vu` 
      ON `task`.`created_by` = `vu`.`id` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `view_users` `vu2` 
      ON `task`.`updated_by` = `vu2`.`id`
```

The `view_users` MySQL View that I use in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s is this:

```
SELECT 
    `user`.`id` AS `id`,
    `role`.`role` AS `role`,
    `branch`.`name` AS `branch_name`,
    `address`.`city` AS `city`
FROM
    ((((`user` `user`
    JOIN `role` `role` ON ((`user`.`role_id` = `role`.`id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `branch` `branch` ON ((`branch`.`id` = `user`.`branch_id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `address` `address` ON ((`address`.`id` = `user`.`address_id`)))
```

The result of the `EXPLAIN` is the following:
[image]

Here I noticed that `task.created_by` has `PRIMARY` `select_type`, while `task.updated_by` is treated as `DERIVED`, and because of this, MySQL will scan 54876 rows when `LEFT OUTER JOIN`ing the `view_users` View on `task.updated_by`.

After this I used `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`, then `SHOW WARNINGS`, and I got the following query that has been "rewritten" by MySQL:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   `task` `task` 
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         `user` `user` 
         JOIN
            `role` `role` 
         LEFT JOIN
            `branch` `branch` 
            ON((`branch`.`id` = `user`.`branch_id`)) 
         LEFT JOIN
            `address` `address` 
            ON((`address`.`id` = `user`.`address_id`)) 
      )
      ON(((`role`.`id` = `user`.`role_id`) 
      AND 
      (
         `user`.`id` = `task`.`created_by` 
      )
)) 
   LEFT JOIN
      `view_users` `vu` 
      ON((`vu`.`id` = `task`.`updated_by`))
```

Here we can see that the `view_users` View that has been joined on `task.created_by` is "resolved", while on `task.updated_by` it will use `view_users`.

Why does MySQL derives Views for some occasions and not for others?

Ideally I would expect that task.updated_by would not be derived, so the performance of the original query would be much better.

Comment: The syntax is not even valid. In the derived table there is the keyword `SELECT` missing and the columns to select. And an alias name for the derived table is also missing and the ON clause `ON(((role.id = user.role_id)` refers to table outside its scope. I guess we can just as well ignore this query. And: a view is a subquery. It makes no difference whether we have the subquery itself or the  view in the query. A view is just for convenience. It saves typing.

Comment: What is uv.id supposed to mean by the way? The view selects from four tables. The id of which of the tables would uv.id refer to? I think you should list all selected columns in the view and use alias names, e.g. `task.is as task_id` so as to make it readable and usuable. And: Are all those outer joins needed? Wouldn't inner joins suffice?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, apologies - I forgot the aliases in my View. Now I have edited it. Regarding LEFT OUTER JOINs, those are generated by Hibernate.

Comment: The optimizer is only so smart. (Eg ideally the left joins of your view would be done once at the end.) Also: What are your keys/indexes? Please read & act on [mcve]. PS I suspect the derived table verison of the view is built when executing the inline version of the view. PPS [Reading...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html) "The first time MySQL needs the subquery result, it materializes that result into a temporary table. Any subsequent time the result is needed, MySQL refers again to the temporary table." Read also re views.